# Vega-Lite "table" using text marks

Tags: vega-lite

Trying to replicate the example shown here:

https://observablehq.com/@mdeagen/vega-lite-table-using-text-marks#count

However, when I add the vegalite code to the online editor I get an error because of the following line of code:

{"filter": {"field": "row_num", "lte": count}},

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega-datasets/next/data/penguins.json"
  },
  "transform": [
    {"window": [{"op": "row_number", "as": "row_num"}]},
    {"filter": {"field": "row_num", "lte": count}},
    {"fold": ["Beak Length (mm)", "Beak Depth (mm)", "Flipper Length (mm)", "Body Mass (g)", "Species", "Island", "Sex"]}
  ],
  "mark": "text",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "row_num", "type": "ordinal", "axis": null},
    "text": {"field": "value", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {"field": "key", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"orient": "top", "labelAngle": 0, "title": null, "domain": false, "ticks": false}, "scale": {"padding": 15}}
  }, "config": {"view": {"stroke": null}}
}
```

Does anyone know a simple fix for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like `count` there is a dynamic variable in the Observable runtime (specified by the slider). You can pass a scalar value for it if you are just using the online editor: `{"filter": {"field": "row_num", "lte": 20}}`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Was actually hoping to include the slider so that no. of rows was dynamic rather than static.                                                                      Would this require a dynamic parameter to be added to the code to create the slider?

Comment: Adding the following parameter works to create a slider....                                                                                           "params": [
    { "name": "count",
      "value": 10,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1, "max": 500, "step": 1}                                                ]                                                                                                                                       BUT unsure what the expression to modify row_num should be and where it goes. THANKS.

Comment: I added some examples of how to create tables in https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/8063 that might be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the link. Hopefully they add the ability to include all columns in the data, with a parameter to reduce the selection in the near future.